# VS2010 app in Win10 and Win11 does not find camera

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, camera, windows-10, windows-11

I am writing here as a last resort to get some light on the problem I am facing.
I have an app that was developed in VB .net (VS2010) that uses EmugCv to capture a webcam image.

The app was installed the same way on all computers (10 computers with win10 and 10 computers with win11).

On Win10, out of every 10 computers only 1 does not run.
On win11, out of every 10 computers, only 1 runs.

As far as I can understand, when it does not run on win10 and win11 the program does not detect the camera. However, Win10 and Win11 detects and installs the drivers correctly and even any other app in windows can show images from the camera.

I literally cannot figure out what makes most win11 computers run the program while on win11 it does not. Least of all, because one of the win11 computers the program runs perfectly.

app to detect the camera